# Set subtitle track using javascript in html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am using the video tag and track tag to show a video with a .vtt subtitle file on my website, as in the code below:

```
<div id="Video">
<video id="player" controls width="1024" height="576">
<source src="video/video00.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
<track id="subtitletrack" label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="subtitle/video02.vtt" default>
</video>
```

This all works fine, but I would like to set the subtitle randomly from an array using javascript:

```
var subArray = ["subtitle/video00.vtt","subtitle/video01.vtt","subtitle/video02.vtt"];
var subtitle = subArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*subArray.length)];
```

Now the variable 'subtitle' is one of three random vtt files.

How can I set the track src to the variable 'subtitle'?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery: `$("#subtitletrack").attr("src", subtitle)`

Answer (score -1):

As Jeremy suggested I used jquery and it works like this:

```
<body>
<video controls autobuffer autoplay id="rearrangements" width="1024" height="576">
<source src="video/video00.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
<track id="subtitles" src="subtitle/video00.vtt" default>
</video>
</body>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var videoArray = ["video/video00.mp4","video/video01.mp4","video/video02.mp4"];
var subArray = ["subtitle/video00.vtt","subtitle/video01.vtt","subtitle/video02.vtt"];
$("#rearrangements").bind('ended', function(){ 
            videonumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
            while (videonumber == lastvideonumber){
            videonumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
            console.log(videonumber);
            }
            $("#subtitles").removeAttr("src");
            $("#rearrangements").attr("src", videoArray[videonumber]);
            $("#subtitles").attr("src", subArray[videonumber]);
            this.play();
        });
</script>
```

But it stops after looping 3 or 4 times maybe there is still a bug somewhere?
Fixed this: it stopped looping when the same subtitlefile was used for the next video, so I put in a short while-loop to make sure the variable was different.

Comment: I don't know, but I'll look into it if I have time today.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, I fixed it. It happens only when the same subtitles are used twice in a row, I think the .attr does not add anything but the removeAttr removes the existing src, leaving nothing.

Comment: Correct, if you are only changing the attribute, then you do not need `removeAttr`.